Programmatically trigger focus on another composable in Jetpack compose
I have composable in two rows comprising as follows

Edit button in one row - when the user clicks this button then

the 2nd row is displayed comprising of

Delete icon and a Cancel icon

When the user clicks the cancel button, then first row is shown. My composable is shown below
@Composable
fun SelectEditBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, isSelectionEnabled: Boolean, selectedNotifications: Map<String, FlexNotification>,
    selectionBarViewState: State<SelectionBarViewState>, onSelectionEnabled: () -> Unit, onDelete: () -> Unit,
    onCancel: () -> Unit
) {
    // if the selection is enabled, then we reset all settings on back navigation
    BackHandler(
        enabled = isSelectionEnabled
    ) {
        if (isSelectionEnabled) {
            onCancel()
        }
    }
    SelectEditTopBar(
        modifier = modifier, isSelectionEnabled = isSelectionEnabled, selectedNotifications = selectedNotifications,
        selectionBarViewState = selectionBarViewState, onSelect = onSelectionEnabled,
        onDelete = onDelete, onCancel = onCancel
    )
}

composables
private fun SelectEditTopBar(
    modifier: Modifier, isSelectionEnabled: Boolean, selectedNotifications: Map<String, FlexNotification>,
    selectionBarViewState: State<SelectionBarViewState>, onSelect: () -> Unit, onDelete: () -> Unit,
    onCancel: () -> Unit
) {
 AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !isSelectionEnabled,
        enter = fadeIn() + expandVertically(),
        exit = fadeOut() + shrinkVertically()
    ) {
        Row(modifier = modifier) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            val minDimensions = dimensionResource(
                id =
                when (windowSizeClass.windowWidthSizeClass) {
                    WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> com.myproject.R.dimen.margin6x
                    else -> com.myproject.R.dimen.margin4x
                }
            )
            val selectedBarViewStateRemember by remember {selectionBarViewState}
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = minDimensions, minWidth = minDimensions)
                    .wrapContentSize().focusRequester(focusRequester).focusProperties {
                        canFocus = selectedBarViewStateRemember.isEditButtonInFocus
                        next =
                    }
                    .focusable(),
                hierarchy = ButtonHierarchy.Flat,
                onClick = onSelect,
                color = MyTheme.colors.foregroundPrimary,
                text = stringResource(id = com.myproject.R.string.edit),
                textStyle = MyTheme.typography.smallBold.copy(
                    color = MyTheme.colors.foregroundPrimary
                )
            )
        }
    }
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isSelectionEnabled,
        enter = fadeIn() + expandVertically(),
        exit = fadeOut() + shrinkVertically()
    ) {
        val minimumDimensions = dimensionResource(
            id = when (windowSizeClass.windowWidthSizeClass) {
                WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> com.myproject.R.dimen.margin6x
                else -> com.myproject.R.dimen.margin4x
            }
        )
        SelectEditInnerTopBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = minimumDimensions, minWidth = minimumDimensions)
                .wrapContentWidth(),
            selectionBarViewState = selectionBarViewState, focusRequester = focusRequester,
            selectedNotifications = selectedNotifications, onDelete = onDelete, onCancel = onCancel
        )
    }

}


@Composable
private fun SelectEditInnerTopBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, focusRequester: FocusRequester, selectedNotifications: Map<String, FlexNotification>,
    selectionBarViewState: State<SelectionBarViewState>, onDelete: () -> Unit,
    onCancel: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.padding(horizontal = MyTheme.dimens.grid_1))) {
        val textStyle = when (LocalWindowSizeClassValues.current.windowWidthSizeClass) {
            WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium, WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> MyTheme.typography.mediumRegular
            else -> MyTheme.typography.smallRegular
        }
        val isAnyNotificationSelected by remember(selectedNotifications) {
            derivedStateOf {
                selectedNotifications.isNotEmpty()
            }
        }
        val selectedNotificationsCount by remember(selectedNotifications) {
            derivedStateOf {
                selectedNotifications.size
            }
        }
        QuickFilter(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .focusable()
            ,
            textStyle = textStyle,
            text = "",
            enabled = isAnyNotificationSelected,
            hierarchy = QuickFilterHierarchy.ACTION,
            onCheckedChange = {
                onDelete()
            }
        ) { _, _ ->
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.semantics {
                    drawableId = com.myproject.R.drawable.ui_ic_playbook_delete_black_16dp
                },
                imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = com.myproject.R.drawable.ui_ic_playbook_delete_black_16dp),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = if (isAnyNotificationSelected) {
                    MyTheme.colors.foregroundPrimary
                } else {
                    MyTheme.colors.foregroundDisabled
                }
            )
            val quickFilterStateDescription = stringResource(id =
                if (isAnyNotificationSelected) {
                    com.myproject.R.string.enabled_accessibility
                } else {
                    com.myproject.R.string.disabled_accessibility
                }
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .padding(
                        start = dimensionResource(id = com.myproject.R.dimen.marginHalf)
                    )
                    .semantics {
                        stateDescription = quickFilterStateDescription
                    },
                text = stringResource(id = com.myproject.R.string.ui_delete),
                style = if (isAnyNotificationSelected) MyTheme.typography.smallRegular else MyTheme.typography.smallRegular.copy(color = MyTheme.colors.foregroundDisabled),
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                color = if (isAnyNotificationSelected) {
                    MyTheme.colors.foregroundPrimary
                } else {
                    MyTheme.colors.foregroundDisabled
                }
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        if (isAnyNotificationSelected) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .padding(horizontal = MyTheme.dimens.padding)
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = MyTheme.dimens.iconSize)
                    .wrapContentSize(),
                text = pluralStringResource(
                    id = com.myprojct.R.plurals.selection_count,
                    selectedNotificationsCount,
                    selectedNotificationsCount
                ),
                style = MyTheme.typography.smallRegular
            )
        }

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .focusProperties {
                    if (selectionBarViewState.value.isDeleteButtonInFocus) {
                        canFocus = true
                    }
                }.focusable(),
            hierarchy = ButtonHierarchy.Flat,
            text = stringResource(id = com.myproject.R.string.cancel),
            textStyle = MyTheme.typography.smallRegular.copy(
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline,
                color = MyTheme.colors.foregroundPrimary
            ),
            onClick = onCancel
        )
    }
}

This is what the fist row looks like

If the user clicks the Edit button

This is what I want to do for accessibility purposes
If the user clicks on the Edit button, I want to focus on Delete button. Similarly, if the user clicks Cancel button, I want to focus on Edit button.
Is there a way I can do that in Jetpack compose?

Can you explain why this doesn't work for you? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/touch-input/focus/change-focus-behavior#request-keyboard
